# CloudFront Signed Cookies Keeping Session State for API Gateway Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm using the following technology stack for my web application

- CloudFront as a Proxy and CDN
- S3 orign to CloudFront to serve AngularJS application
- APIGateway origin to CloudFront for REST API
- Cognito UserPools with CognitoAuthorizer for authentication in API Gateway

To store Web Application user session, I usually stores the issued JWT from Cognito in a Client-Side Cookie, HTML5 LocalStorage or SessionStorage.

However I'm curious to know that CloudFront Signed Cookies can provide a session state for the Web Applications. I'm hoping to use Signed Cookies to store JWT and use Edge Lambda to map a Signed Cookie to Authorization Header to authenticate API Gateway. I'm interested to know

1. Is using CloudFront Signed Cookies to store JWT will work?
2. Is it a good approach to store session state in Signed Cookies for web applications?
3. If so, what are the best practices around it? I'm not sure using Edge Lambda is the right approach.

Comment: *"However I recently found CloudFront Signed Cookies can provide a session state for the Web Applications"*  That doesn't sound right.  Signed cookies are just another way for the browser to present the same key/value pairs that are used in a CloudFront signed URL. Where did you see or hear this?

Comment: I understood from the following link https://arinenote.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/creating-amazon-cloudfront-signing-cookies-in-node-js/ since if we can create a cookie from a API Gateway endpoint, I could be able to (Not verified) to store a JWT in the cookie. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront Signed Cookies doesn't have a way of storing custom data. Because of that, storing the AWS Cognito UserPool issued id_token inside the Signed Cookie is not possible. Therefore the questioned approach is not possible to proceed with.

**Alternative Approach**

Instead, the login API Gateway route can set both the SignedCookie and a separate Cookie to store JWT token where the Cookie is validated at a pre-configured Edge Lambda and added to the Authorization header, before forwarding the request to API Gateway.